# Way to optimise Python nested list loops

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, bit

I'm currently working on this function in Python 3:

```
def BToBInter(Array):
    NewA = []
    Amount = 23
    Res = 0
    M = len(Array) - 24
    for P in range(M):
        for I in Array[P:P+24]:
            if I == 1:
                Res += (1 << Amount)
            Amount -= 1
        NewA.append(Res)
        Amount = 23
        Res = 0
    return NewA
```

The idea is:

- Input 'Array' is a Python list of bits (1's and 0's);
- First, bits 0 to 23 of the list are read off, turned into an integer and added to list 'NewA';
- Then bits 1 to 24 are read off, then 2 to 25, 3 to 26 and so on.

So a bit list of N bits produces an integer list of N-24 integers.

This runs fairly slow with large bit lists. Cython helps, but I sense the code could be more efficient to begin with. I use list comprehensions a lot, but I'm unsure how to apply them to these nested loops. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you're implementing a moving window; you can do this with `itertools`, see e.g. https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/blob/master/boltons/iterutils.py#L247

Comment: How large are the arrays? How fast do you need the algorithm to be? And by the way, please don't use capitalized names for variables and functions.... those are meant to be for Classes and only cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have time to check whether all of the edge cases have been treated correctly, but here's an idea.  Right now there are (potentially) 24 shifts and sums you have to do for each window.  But when you've already got a value for a window, the value of that window shifted by 1 can be computed without looping over the whole 24: all you need to do is subtract off the component due to the element which has fallen out of the window; multiply that by 2; and add the component due to the new element which has entered the window.  To be concrete:

```
def new_bit(arr, window_size):
    start = sum(1 << (window_size-i-1) for i in range(window_size) if arr[i])
    results = [start]
    maxpow = 1 << (window_size-1)
    for j in range(window_size, len(arr)-1):
        last = results[-1]
        common = last - arr[j-window_size] * maxpow
        new = common * 2 + arr[j]
        results.append(new)
    return results
```

which gives me

```
>>> w = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(30)]
>>> BToBInter(w)
[7981231, 15962463, 15147711, 13518207, 10259198, 3741180]
>>> new_bit(w,24)
[7981231, 15962463, 15147711, 13518207, 10259198, 3741180]
>>> %timeit BToBInter(w)
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.5 µs per loop
>>> %timeit new_bit(w, 24)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop
>>> w = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(10**6)]
>>> %timeit BToBInter(w)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.56 s per loop
>>> %timeit new_bit(w, 24)
1 loops, best of 3: 771 ms per loop
```

As I said, there might be an error in the implementation.  But the basic idea of speeding up sliding window calculations by reusing as many calculations as possible from the previous step is sound, and is very common.

Comment: Nice idea! How about `common = last & ((1<<window_size-1)-1)`, or maybe even save this mask beforehand.

Comment: DSM, your method shaved several seconds off when I used it in my program. jonrsharpe, I'll look into Itertools to see what I can do with them. Despite what the comments box recommends, my thanks to both of you.